# How to check if subversion is installed using Shell Script on mac

Tags: shell, unix

I am writing a little shell script to help setup a production/development environment for some of our software and part of it requires subversion.

I need a way to check if subversion is installed on a *nix(usually mac) machine.

I was thinking of checking if **export SUBVERSION_HOME=/opt/subversion** exists in .profile since that is what the devs use here, but are there any more concrete ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something crude:

```
which svn
```

In a test:

```
if [[ -n $(which svn) ]]; then
    # do something
fi
```

**Caveat:** this would fail in the very unlikely even that someone has a `svn` installed that is not actually Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like this maybe?

```
which svn > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "subversion is not installed"
    exit 1
fi
```